# google-apps script - loops

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I have a project I been working on to read data from one sheet and iterate through the designated columns grab that data and place it on a template that will be uploaded to Google ads. See the code below (A SIMPLE LOOP IS NEEDED SEE MY CODE FOR COMMENTS!). Please note that i'm new to this and it may look like an eye sore. I been stuck on this for a while now trying literally everything I found with no success. if you need additional attachments or clarification please let me know.

```js
//============================================================================*
// This program is an inventory based program that will create AdGroups based *
// On your current inventory Spreadsheet on your G-Drive                      *
// ===========================================================================*
function main() {

  var feedCSVname = "FILE_NAME.csv"
  var feedSheetName = "INVENTORY SHEET"
  var TemplateURL = "SHEET_URL_HERE"
  var Template_sheetName = "TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME"
  var push_sheetName = "Upload"
  var done = "Done"

  // ==== Parse CSV file and dump all contents to inventory sheet =========
  var feedFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(feedCSVname).next();
  var feedData = Utilities.parseCsv(feedFile.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var Template = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(TemplateURL);
  var feedSheet = Template.getSheetByName(feedSheetName);
  feedSheet.clear().getRange(1, 1, feedData.length, feedData[0].length).setValues(feedData);
  // Create a new columns "Status" so we can loop through
  feedSheet.getRange('BI1').setValue('Status');

  //==================== Feed Column Locations ============================
  var CidColumn = 2;
  var sellingPriceColumn = 10;
  var yearColumn = 13;
  var makeColumn = 14;
  var modelColumn = 15;
  var trimColumn = 16;
  var dealernameColumn = 39;
  var countofmakemodelyearColumn = 47;
  var lowest_priceColumn = 52;
  var mm_lowest_priceColumn = 53;
  var m_lowest_priceColumn = 54;
  var URL1Column = 58;
  var URL2Column = 59;
  var URL3Column = 60;
  var status = 61;
  var feedRows = 2 // Since row 1 has headers
  var lastrow = feedSheet.getLastRow();

  //======================= Feed Row Data ================================

  var sellingPrice = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, sellingPriceColumn).getValue();
  var year = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, yearColumn).getValue();
  var make = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, makeColumn).getValue();
  var model = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, modelColumn).getValue();
 
  var dealername = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, dealernameColumn).getValue();

  var URL1 = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, URL1Column).getValue();
  var URL2 = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, URL2Column).getValue();
  var URL3 = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, URL3Column).getValue();

  //==================== Write Data To Template ==========================
  // I need to loop this process
  var templateSheet = Template.getSheetByName(Template_sheetName);

  templateSheet.getRange('B2').setValue("Campaign Name");
  templateSheet.getRange('B3').setValue(make);
  templateSheet.getRange('B4').setValue(model);
  templateSheet.getRange('B5').setValue(year);
  templateSheet.getRange('D2').setValue(URL1);
  templateSheet.getRange('D3').setValue(URL2);
  templateSheet.getRange('D4').setValue(URL3);
  feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, status).setValue(done);

  // when this column and row = "Done" then go to next row


  var readStatusColumn = feedSheet.getRange(feedRows, status).getValue();
  if (readStatusColumn == done) {
    //Then go to next row loop process

  }

 
  //================ Copy all data to push sheet =========================

  //Copy contents of the Template sheet and paste to the Upload sheet
  var copyRange = templateSheet.getRange('A8:J113');
  var pushSheet = Template.getSheetByName(push_sheetName);
  var paste2pushSheet = pushSheet.getRange(pushSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  copyRange.copyTo(paste2pushSheet, {
    contentsOnly: true
  });
  //End Loop
}
```

Comment: B2,B3,B4, and B5 are all next to each other.  You don't need to set the values individually.  `var colm_B_Values = [["Campaign Name"],[make],[model],[year]]; var startRow = 2; var startColumn =2;templateSheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,colm_B_Values.length,1).setValues(colm_B_Values);`

Comment: What's the problem? Errors? Incorrect behavior? Or just "ugly code"?

Comment: I need to perform a loop. I'm pulling data from a sheet and placing it on a template then I need to go to the next row then the next row and so on. see this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqOpR5POOKU go to 6:17 for the code. This was written in VBA and I took the same logic from this code and modified it. all i'm missing is the loop part. I commented in my code where I think it should be placed. I hope this helps.

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks for the response. I tried this and it did not have the results I needed. see my above response for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: All these views and no one here cannot assist me with this? Didn't think this was rocket science for such a forum O.o this is just sad . . . . . . .

Comment: There is no problem description here, no error message given, just "I tried something - I won't tell you what I tried, but I tried it - and it wasn't right, so tell me the answer." That's not a good question for a Q&A website (this is not a discussion/help forum). [Edit your question to include your specific goal, your research (read anything about loops in JavaScript?), how you have attempted to modify your code, and how those modifications did or did not work.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @tehhowch what more can I say here honestly? Error message? no errors in console, script finished in less than 5 seconds, not producing the results I need. I have have commented previously with a link to a video as well as what I'm trying to achieve. Its all commented in my code. I tried looking at this site from other's posts, w3 schools, google, youtube. see this video youtube.com/watch?v=iqOpR5POOKU and go to 6:17 and it explains EXACTLY what i'm looking for.  is anyone seeing my previous comments? if this is not a help forum then what is this site? Google dev site pointed me here for help.

Comment: @tehhowch what have I tried? a for loop, while loop pretty much all the loops out there https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp. Once again, I cannot grasp it and that's why I'm asking for assistance. Do you really want me to post every single failed attempt to stick in a loop? I thought my comments in my code as well as the youtube video was more than enough for a developer forum to answer within minutes of my post (since a loop is beginner stuff) apparently its some serious complex stuff I'm asking for. 27 days with no answer... where the pros at?

Comment: Your problem description should not be in a video - it should be in your question. Your question has not been well received because you have not presented an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you do not describe the problem or goal in your question itself, and you do not show what you have tried and explained the ways in which they did not achieve your goal or resolve your issue. If you can post an mcve, details in your question, and some loops you've tried, I'm sure we can give a suitable answer.